# Stopping and starting an Interval with the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery

enter code hereso I'm trying to build a sort of chronometer in JavaScript and I'm trying to make it so that when a single button is clicked the setInterval to start the chronometer is started and when I click it again the interval is cleared (clearInterval()). This is what I tried so far, but I don't know how to make it work.

```
$(function(){

var s,min,status,type,interval;

$('#display').on('click', function(){

  function clock(){
    s -= 1;
    if(s<0){
      s = 59;
      min -= 1;
    }
    if(min == 0 && s == 0){
      s = 59;
      min = parseInt($('#break-length').text())-1;
    }
    console.log(min,s);
  }

  if(status == 'active'){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  if(!status || status == 'not active'){
    status = 'active';
    type = 'session'
    s = 60;
    min = parseInt($('#session-length').text())-1;  
    interval = setInterval(function(){clock()},1000)
  }

  status = 'not active';

});
```

});

Comment: This is not a website where you ask people to write code for you. You have to provide proof that you've attempted to actually write the code, and provide a working example.

Comment: @SeanKendle sorry, I forgot to put my code, as soon as I get to my PC I'll do it. I'm kinda new here, so thanks for the advice

Comment: No problem.  Look for the `<>` button to add working "Snippets" next time. Make sure you include any other code bases, like jQuery for example, in the drop down menus on the left.  Put in the full HTML and CSS along with the JavaScript. That way people can see your code, test it, and quickly copy it into their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of onclick function you always set status to 'not active'. Try this:

```
  if(status == 'active'){
    clearInterval(interval);
    status = 'not active';
  } else {
    status = 'active';
    type = 'session'
    s = 60;
    min = parseInt($('#session-length').text())-1;  
    interval = setInterval(function(){clock()},1000)
  }
```

Comment: I knew I was doing that, but I couldn't think of a way to fix it, thank you very much